# How Can I Find Out If PHP COM Is Loaded On Server

Tags: php, com

I have asked my web host to install PHP COM on their Windows Server. They say it has been done but I keep getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in .....
```

I would like to find out if it has been installed correctly.

Is there something like `extension_loaded('COM')` or `(dl('php_com_dotnet.dll'))` that will show me if it has been configured correctly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make a php file like this:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Then scroll down to the loaded extensions/modules and look for it there!

Comment: Have looked in phpinfo but cannot see anything... To be honest though im not sure where I would find it or what it would look like?

Comment: Did you make the PHP page and visit it in your web browser?

Comment: Yes. Just couldn't find any mention of COM but not sure where I would find it. Did a search on page for "COM" but found nothing.

Comment: Well in that case then, they didn't install it right!